# Can we remove the lines of file committed in certain revision?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

### For example:

SVN Rev - 100:

```
This is main file content.    
This is commited content till 100.
```

SVN Rev - 101:

```
This is main file content.
Modification done on Rev 2.
This is commited content till 100.
```

SVN Rev - 102:

```
This is main file content.    
Modification done on Rev 2.    
This is committed content till 100.    
Modification done on Rev 3.
```

Is there any SVN tool or way to get the committed content of Rev 100 and 102 ?

Output should be:

```
This is main file content.    
This is committed content till 100.    
Modification done on Rev 3.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. The whole point of using SVN is to store different versions of a file which you can lookup by revision.

That being said, you could use [`svn cat`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.cat.html) to get the contents of the file at `r100`, and again at `r102`, then *manually merge* the contents of the outputs to get the intended result.

Answer (score 0):

Because you task, translated to plain English is "Undo changes, made in revision 101" and "undo revision" in SVN-lingua is "Reverse merge", you have, as result, reverse-merge revision 101 (fully or only for file `file.txt`, if other files are affected by r101)

Read [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo), understand it, use in Working Copy

`svn merge -c -101 ^/file.txt`

and get **only locally undoed** changed in file